# Tethered shooting with Sony a57 - impossible?

Tags: lightroom, sony, tethering

I have a Sony a57 and today I tried to set it up with a tethered capture in Lightroom.  Lightroom couldn't even see the camera.  Is there any way to get this working, or are they just not compatible?

Comment: There is a currently open kickstarter project to provide universal(ish) DSLR tethering. Subscribe. Hope.

Comment: Only 4 cameras from Sony support shooting un-tethered with the ATG AK1 Un-Tethered Systems. Why worry or need to tethered when you can shoot wirelessly, right?

Comment: Are you saying I can shoot wirelessly and have it insta-appear in Lightroom?  If so, how?  Are you referring to Eye-Fi card?

Comment: ATG AK1 Un-Tethered Systems appears to be a scam.  Only seems to exist in comments in various message boards and blogs.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't see that this product actually exists. Flagged as spam.

http://photo.net/canon-eos-digital-camera-forum/00XQ5w
http://www.flickr.com/groups/1246778@N22/discuss/72157623070406845/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sony eSupport page says:

> It is not possible to control the camera from a computer with the USB connection. Remote camera operation using a computer is not supported.

Sony models listed include SLT A5x series.

So, tethering or any other kind of control thru USB is not supported. This seems like not only Lightroom but including all tethering software and makes searching not worth your while.

Some control thru USB-cable (including shutter release) is possible with Sony models

- DSLR A700 Series
- DSLR A800 Series
- DSLR A900 Series
- SLT A90   Series

Answer (score 8):

**It is impossible with Lightroom as the camera is not supported. See the [supported list](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support-lightroom-4.html).**

You will have to find other tethering software and check their requirements one-by-one. As a general rule, if your camera is neither Canon nor Nikon, there are far less chances of being supported by anyone else than the manufacturer. So, check with Sony first, they *may* have software for that at an additional cost. While it is probably possible to implement, it may be the case that it just has not been for this camera.

Comment: Found [this](http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=C1001016) on Sony eSupport Q&A-page: "Can the camera be controlled from a computer (aka tethered shooting) when connected with the USB cable? 
Solution:
It is not possible to control the camera from a computer with the USB connection. Remote camera operation using a computer is not supported."